# Find all files matching 'name' on linux system, and search with them for 'text'

Tags: linux, command-line, find, grep

I need to find all instances of 'filename.ext' on a linux system and see which ones contain the text 'lookingfor'.

Is there a set of linux command line operations that would work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```bash
find / -type f -name filename.ext -exec grep -l 'lookingfor' {} +
```

Using a `+` to terminate the command is more efficient than `\;` because `find` sends a whole batch of files to `grep` instead of sending them one by one. This avoids a fork/exec for every single file which is found.

A while ago I did some testing to compare the performance of `xargs` vs `{} +` vs `{} \;` and I found that `{} +` was faster. Here are some of my results:

```
time find . -name "*20090430*" -exec touch {} +
real    0m31.98s
user    0m0.06s
sys     0m0.49s

time find . -name "*20090430*" | xargs touch
real    1m8.81s
user    0m0.13s
sys     0m1.07s

time find . -name "*20090430*" -exec touch {} \;
real    1m42.53s
user    0m0.17s
sys     0m2.42s
```

Comment: I'd only add the `--color` to `grep`, I believe it is a lot easier to see things. Actually, I just realized it doesn't take the alias I defined in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 9):

Go to respective directory and type the following command.

> find . -name "*.ext" | xargs grep
>   'lookingfor'

Answer (score 3):

A more simple one would be:

```bash
find / -type f -name filename.ext -print0 | xargs -0 grep  'lookingfor'
```

The `-print0` and `-0` options mitigate the issue of large numbers of files in a single directory.

Comment: `-print0` and `-0` has nothing to do with the large number of files. It ensures that `find | xargs` works when some file have space characters in their names.

Comment: Didier you're absolutely right in this,here is the excerpt from the man page for everyone else,  -print0
              True; print the full file name on the standard output,  followed
              by  a  null  character  (instead  of  the newline character that
              -print uses).  This allows file names that contain  newlines  or
              other  types  of white space to be correctly interpreted by pro‐
              grams that process the find output.  This option corresponds  to
              the -0 option of xargs.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find / -type f -name filename.ext -exec grep -H -n 'lookingfor' {} \;
```

`find` searches recursively starting from the root `/` for files named `filename.ext` and for every found occurrence it runs grep on the file name searching for `lookingfor` and if found prints the line number (`-n`) and the file name (`-H`).

Comment: Given the huge number of files, it is much more efficient to use `xargs` that will start `grep` only once, as in digen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following command the simplest way:

```bash
    grep -R --include="filename.ext" lookingfor
```

or add `-i` to search case insensitive:

```bash
    grep -i -R --include="filename.ext" lookingfor
```