# Grep only last line after find needed files

Tags: bash, search, grep, find

Hi guys I have an extended question from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786606/find-all-files-matching-name-on-linux-system-and-search-with-them-for-text?rq=1)

I need to find some files given file name and use grep on the last lines of these files to find a certain string.

I currently have:

`find my_dir/ -name "*filename*" | xargs grep 'lookingfor'`

I'm new to using these commands so much help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example do:

```
find my_dir/ -name "*filename*" -exec sh -c "tail -200 {} | grep lookingfor" \;
```

setting `200` to the number of last lines you want.

Comment: This way he loses names of files

Comment: @user3159253 He can just add `-H` flag to [tag:grep] to fix that

Comment: No, he couldn't. tail eats the filename, and grep works just on `STDIN`

Comment: You actually may try: `tail /path/to/file | grep -H lookingfor` gives me `(standard input):lookingfor`

Comment: @user3159253 Nice catch, +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

```
find  my_dir -name '*filename*' -type f \
     -exec /bin/bash -c '(tail -5 "$1" | grep -q lookingfor) && echo "$1"' _ {} \;
```

This way you will correctly handle all (well, hopefully all :-)) filenames, even those with " and other strange symbols within. Also I would suggest explicitly call /bin/bash because /bin/sh may be linked on a crippled sh-variant like `ash`, `sash` and `dash`.

Comment: Also it seems I've just found a bug/a strange behaviour in bash: `bash -c 'echo \$@=\"$@\";' a b c` gives me `$@="b c"` :-). That's why I need an additional `_` between the command argument `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Using find + awk + wc -l

```
find  my_dir -name '*filename*' -type f -exec awk 'NR>count-100{print FILENAME, $0}' count=$(wc -l < {}) {} +
```

Adjust 100 to the number of last lines you want.